# adding 3 variables in Python

Tags: python, addition

I would like to know what is wrong with my logic here:

```
def add_three(num1, num2, num3)
        return (2 + 3 + 4)
print (add_three)
```

How do I assign values to variables and return the sum?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: You should format your text so we can see the code as code. You are missing the `:` at the end of `def`, didn't include `()` for the call to `add_three()`, nor did you provide any arguments. See example in answer below.

Comment: Look at the answers below. You need to have arguments when you are calling functions without default values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def add_three(num1, num2, num3): 
    return (num1 + num2 + num3) 

print(add_three(2,3,4)) #result: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def add_three(num1, num2, num3):
    return (num1 + num2 + num3)

print (add_three ( 1, 2, 3) )
print (add_three ( 2, 3, 4) )
```

Output looks like this:

```
6
9
```

Answer (score 0):

Always remember than function that are created must be called with (). You can create functions with default values or user specified values. It depends on the result that you want.

If you want different results with different number combination, you should specify numbers in your call.

```
def add_three(num1,num2,num3):
return(num1+num2+num3)

print (add_three(2,3,4)) #Ans 9
print (add_three(2,3,6)) #Ans 11
```

If you want to get the same result you call the function, you can set default values like this. This gives you a default value of 9 on each call.

```
def add_three(num1=2,num2=3,num3=4):
return(num1+num2+num3)

print (add_three())
```